# How can I solve word fusion errors with phrase suggester in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, search-engine

I'm using Phrase Suggester feature in Elasticsearch to obtain possible corrections of the given query(correctly spelled or misspelled). However, I confronted with a problem. When I make searching with the query in unified shape like "germanyberlin", it returns "germany berlin" in possible correction candidates. However, when I query "straw berries", It doesn't give any possible correction candidates like "strawberries". I mean it doesn't return any unified results/candidates. How can I obtain correct candidates for the case which incorrectly seperated words/phrases ?

Here is my search body:

```
{
  "suggest": {
  "phrase_suggester" : {
    "text" : "straw berries",
    "phrase" : {
      "field" : "place.shingle",
      "size" : 5,
      "max_errors" : 2.0,
      "direct_generator" : [
        {
          "field" : "place.shingle",
          "max_edits" : 2,
          "suggest_mode" : "always"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: From the official doc (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html): "In general the phrase suggester requires special mapping up front to work."
Did you try that?

Comment: @YuriG sure I did. It doesn't covers the case aforementioned